# Getting column value using DataTables jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using [DataTables Table jQuery plugin](https://datatables.net/) to show some data in a tabular format.
It looks like this:

[image]

The last column, the one with the name 'Status', has hyperlinks that the user can click on.

What I am not able to figure out is to get the 'Name' column value when the hyperlink for that row is clicked!!!

So when you click on the 'Disable' link for the first row, I want to get the value 'force awakens'.

I have not included any code here as it is very straight forward that I used from the creator's website.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try searching the parent.siblings().eq(0) for the hyperlink in onclick event. That will give the name column value for the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get specific row content through the API - `table.row().data()` - by passing the `<tr>` parent element :

```js
$("#example").on('click', 'a', function() {
    alert('Name is: '+table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data()[0]);
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/6s7kgx07/**